Angular Owl Carousel isn't horizontally its vertically
In my Angular project, I used an Owl Carousel in my home-component.html in here as it can be seen:
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="products-title">New Arrivals</h1>
    <div class="slider">
      <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions" class="owl-stage">
        <ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let product of products">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': isDarkTheme ? '#5eda5e' : '#3b5b2d'}">
              <img class="product-image" [src]="product.imgSrc" [alt]="product.name">
              <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name | translate}}</h2>
              <p class="product-description">{{ product.description | translate}}</p>
              <p class="product-price">{{ product.price | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.2-2' }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </owl-carousel-o>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

However,  my cards aren't displayed horizontally. But I want them to be vertically. Even display: flex didn't solve my problem. Plus, when I tried to inspect via browser the <owl-carousel-o></owl-carousel-o\> has the class actually owl-stage which I also added but with even giving a display: flex to it didn't work.
I tried to make my cards which contain the product details and images horizontal actually. Here is my app-component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'GreenGrocery';
  products: Product[] = [];
  fruit: any;
  fruit_title: any;
  isDarkTheme: boolean = false;

  // Initialize dark_mode and light_mode with translation keys
  dark_mode: string = 'assets/img/crescent-moon.png';
  light_mode: string = 'assets/img/sunny.png';

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, public translate: TranslateService, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    // Set default language
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    // Set initial language if needed
    this.translate.use('en');
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'tr']);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products = this.productService.getProducts();
    this.isDarkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === "Dark";
    this.translate.get('assets/img/crescent-moon.png').subscribe((res: string) => {
      this.dark_mode = res;
    });
    this.translate.get('assets/img/sunny.png').subscribe((res: string) => {
      this.light_mode = res;
    });
    this.setBodyBackground();
    this.productText();
  }

  switchLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }

  ChangeLang(event: any) {
    const lang = event.target.value;
    this.switchLanguage(lang);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', this.isDarkTheme ? 'Dark' : 'Light');
    this.languageBackground();
  }

  storeThemeSelection() {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', this.isDarkTheme ? 'Dark' : 'Light');
    this.setBodyBackground();
    this.productText();
    this.footerBackground();
    this.cardBackground();
  }

  private setBodyBackground() {
    const backgroundColor = this.isDarkTheme ? '#3b5b2d' : '#5eda5e';
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', backgroundColor);
  }

  private productText() {
    const color = this.isDarkTheme ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'color', color);
  }

  private footerBackground() {
    const footerBackgroundColor = this.isDarkTheme ? '#4d4d4d' : '#ffffff';
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.querySelector('.footer'), 'background-color', footerBackgroundColor);
  }
 
  private languageBackground() {
    const color = this.isDarkTheme ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'color', color);
  }

  private cardBackground() {
    const cardBackground = this.isDarkTheme ? '#5eda5e' : '#3b5b2d';
    const cardContents = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content');
    cardContents.forEach(cardContent => {
        this.renderer.setStyle(cardContent, 'background-color', cardBackground);
    });
  }

  customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    pullDrag: false,
    dots: true,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ['', ''],
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      740: {
        items: 3
      },
      940: {
        items: 4
      }
    },
    nav: true
  }
}


Normally, you can't directly manipulate other component's style through your component. Therefore, your approach should be like:

Check whether someone else's component has this kind of configuration? If not stay tuned for the second item hahaha
In this case we should leverage our superpower, as you know superpowers need to be under the control. The name of it is ng-deep. ng-deep helps us to manipulate any component's style. However, it might affect every place accross the app. You know, we typically don't want these kind of risky things. One awesome thing is using ng-deep with :host. :host helps us to encapsulate that ng-deep within only that component. Therefore, you only manipule that component's style and styles inside that component. In your home.component.css, you can basically update your style like this:

:host {
  ::ng-deep .owl-stage {
    display: flex;
  }

  .product-image {
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .card {
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .card-content {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}


Thank you for your help. My cards are ordered vertical now but now I face with another issue which always forces to display 3 cards at the same time despite I tried to solve it by myself. I want to display 1 card when its at mobile, 2 cards when its at tablet and 3 cards when its at desktop. I even deleted    event.preventDefault(); from ngx-owl-carousel-o.js but it didn't work. Here is the video explaining my problem: file:///C:/Users/W11/Desktop/Goodfellas%20Green%20Grocery%20-%20Google%20Chrome%202024-04-15%2015-31-01.mp4

If my link doesn't work please let me know
